# Enrich for genes expressed in the plasma membrane

Tags: seurat

I have a list of cell markers differentially expressed between 2 groups of cells, that I got with the FindMarkers command in Seurat. I want to enrich for those genes that are expressed in the cell membrane. Are there any specific tools/commands I can use to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "enrich" test if some group is differently expressed or retrieve more information about those genes from other sources?

Answer (score 1):

You can do functional enrichment analysis, for instance with `gProfiler` in R and see if your marker genes are enriched in any GO term related with the plasma membrane.

Alternatively, you can generate a list with genes whose product are located at the plasma membrane and perform Gene Set Enrichment Analysis, for instance with `fgsea` in R.